# Angular - Typescript variables scope

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

I'm brand new in angular. I'm trying to create a auth-guard which send a post request to the backend, and validate the `JWT`. If `JWT` is valid guard should allow the access of the requested component. This is how my `auth.guard.ts` looks like:

```
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    
    if (this.loginService.isLoggedIn() && this.loginService.isValidateJwt() == 1) {
      console.log("AuthGuard return to requestet page!")
      return true;

    }
    else {

      console.log("AuthGuard redirect to login page!")
      this.router.navigate(['login']);

      return false;
    }

  }
```

This is how the `loginService` relevant part looks like:

```
  isLoggedIn(){

    let token=localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    let username=localStorage.getItem("username");

    if(token==undefined || token=='' || token==null || username==undefined || username == '' || username==null){
      console.log("LoginService isLoggedIn token and username NOT FOUND in local storage!");
      return false;

    }
    else {
      console.log("LoginService isLoggedIn token and username FOUND in local storage! Stat validate JWT!");
      return true;

    }
  }

  isValidateJwt() : number {

    console.log("isValidateJwt invoked!")
    var isvalid = 0

    this.http.post(this.validate_url, new ValidateRequest(localStorage.getItem("jwt") , localStorage.getItem("username"))).subscribe(

        (response:any)=>{
          // success
          console.log("isValidateJwt isValid: " + response.isValid);
          isvalid = response.isValid;

        },
        error=>{
          // error
          console.error(error);
          //window.location.href="/dashboard"

        }
    )
    console.log("isValidateJwt returning: " + isvalid)
    return isvalid;

  }
```

This is how my backend response looks like:

```
{
  "isValid": 1,
  "message": "JWT is VALID!"
}
```

1. I created two Item in the local storage while login process (username / jwt)
2. When the user would like to access a component that is protected, the guard calls the `isLoggidIn` and `isValidateJwt` functions.
3. The `isLoggedin` function reads the localStorage and if username and jwt exists then it returns `true`
4. The `isValidateJwt` function calls the backend and validate the jwt
5. If the `JWT` is valid, backend returns isValid = 0 in the response object and I store it to the `isValid` variable inside the `isValidateJwt` function, but when the function finally returns the value of `isValid` variable will be 0 again.
6. I set up the backend it's always return isValid = 0

I think it is something related to variables scope, but i don't understand why my isValid variable set back to zero.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why does my isvalid variable value change to 0 while i always set it to 1 Sorry

Comment: The mistake is not related to scope but rather to asynchronous and especially `Observable` usage'. I'd recommend reading more about it.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I will read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to put it in to words your `isValidateJwt` method looks like this:

1. Set isValid to zero
2. Some time in the future validate the jwt, don't really know when.
3. Return isValid if the validation got executed.

So your isValidateJwt should return an observable or a promise

```
 isValidateJwt() : Observable<boolean> {
   return this.http.post(this.validate_url, new ValidateRequest(localStorage.getItem("jwt"), localStorage.getItem("username")))
    .pipe(map(
       (response:any) =>{
          // success
          console.log("isValidateJwt isValid: " + response.isValid);
          return response.isValid;
        }));
  }
```

And then you also need to return an observable from your guard method:

```
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    
    if (!this.loginService.isLoggedIn()){
       this.router.navigate(['login']);
       return false;
    }
    return this.loginService.isValidateJwt().pipe(map((result) => {                               
           if (!result) this.router.navigate(['login']);
           return result;
      }));
    }
  }
```

Comment: i copied this code and is shows at isValidateJwt: "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value." and there is an error too: "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'"

Comment: The backend isValid respone is an Integer not a boolean 1 if jwt is valid 0 is jwt is not valid.

Comment: You need to import map from rxjs/operators and in javascript 0 == false

Comment: Error: src/app/services/login.service.ts:63:21 - error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
63   isValidateJwt() : Observable<boolean> {

Comment: Error: src/app/services/login.service.ts:64:123 - error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.
64     this.http.post(this.validate_url, new ValidateRequest(localStorage.getItem("jwt"), localStorage.getItem("username"))).map(

Comment: The funtion called on the `post` result should be `pipe` not `map`. Like this: `this.http.post(...).pipe(map(...))`

Comment: Thank you, but there are still error with isValidate function: Error: src/app/services/login.service.ts:64:21 - error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
64   isValidateJwt() : Observable<boolean> {

Comment: return this.http.post(this.validate_url, new ValidateRequest(localStorage.getItem("jwt"), localStorage.getItem("username"))) this is the proper way. Can you please modify, your answer? And i will accept it! Thank you!

Comment: Sure, there you go